# MS Excel 2016 formatting glitch? unexpected rounding up to quadrilles when using formula with COUNTIFS

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am dividing a COUNTIFS function with a COUNTIFS function to calculate percentage of occurrences of something.

The formula returns numbers rounded up to nearest quartille even when I remove all formatting from the cell.

I calculated numbers manually, and it shows that numbers returned by the formula are rounded to the nearest quartille.

1) Is the problem in the formula?

```
=COUNTIFS(B2025:B7017;"*"&$M9&"*";A2025:A7017; "*"&$R$7&"*";C2025:C7017;"<0")/COUNTIFS(B2025:B7017;"*"&$M9&"*"; A2025:A7017;"*"&$R$7&"*")
```

2) Is the problem in the formatting?

3) What am I missing?

Comment: it is not a glitch, if you have not specifically changed the formatting then it is not doing anything out of the ordinary. Just apply whatever formatting you wish to see the column/cell

Comment: yes. also the results are rounded to 0, 0.25, 0.50, 0,75, 1.00 or 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%

Comment: ohh ok that does sound odd then, I tried creating this error myself but  I did not get anything like this

Comment: that's useful feedback too. thanks. problem persists though.

Comment: Please show an example of your data that recreates the problem. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question